# In Azure Pipeline YAML, how to make stage run even though a job in previous stage fails, using succeeded('JobName')

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to make my second stage run even though one of the two jobs in the first stage fails, but I cannot get it to work as expected with the job status check function `succeeded('JobName')`.

In the following YAML pipeline, I would expect it to run *Stage2* even though *Job2* fails, as long as *Job1* succeeds, but it does not:

```
stages:
  - stage: Stage1
    jobs:
      - job: Job1
        steps:
          - pwsh: echo "Job1"
      - job: Job2
        steps:
          - pwsh: write-error "Job2 error"

  - stage: Stage2
    condition: succeeded('Job1')
    jobs:
      - job: Job3
        steps:
          - pwsh: echo "Job3"
```

How do I get *Stage2* to run even though *Job2* has failed, as long as Job1 has succeeded?

Using `always()` will make *Stage2* run always, but I would like it to depend the success state of *Job1*, regardless of *Job2* state.

Related documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks that this is not possible to handle job result on stage level of the next stage. However you may use this workaraound:

```yaml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: Stage1
    jobs:
      - job: Job1
        steps:
          - pwsh: echo "Job1"
      - job: Job2
        steps:
          - pwsh: write-error "Job2 error"

  - stage: Stage2
    dependsOn: Stage1
    condition: always()
    jobs:
      - job: Job3
        condition: in(stageDependencies.Stage1.Job1.result, 'Succeeded')
        steps:
          - pwsh: echo "Job3"
      - job: Job4
        condition: in(stageDependencies.Stage1.result, 'Succeeded')
        steps:
          - pwsh: echo "Job4"
```

[image]

Documentation for this you have [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-depending-on-job-output).

Comment: This workaround is not super pretty. but works indeed! Nice being able to dot into the stageDependencies result - thanks :)

Comment: Hi Krzysztof; can I ask, is there any particular reason to use the [in function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#in) in the conditions? It looks like the [eq function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#eq) would be appropriate here?

Comment: eq is enough ;) I just modified what I found in docs. It was just faster :) Good spot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is possible now. Example from Microsoft...

```
stages:
- stage: A
  condition: false
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: echo Job A1
- stage: B
  condition: in(dependencies.A.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Canceled')
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
    - script: echo Job B1
```

Documentation: [Stage to stage dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-to-stage-dependencies)

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it might look like the documentation at the time of my question. In this example the condition in stage B is related to stage A (stage to stage), while what I was originally looking for was a stage B to job A1 condition, but that was apparently not supported.